# Trying to backup iPhone to external HDD on windows using iTunes mklink

Tags: backup, iphone, mklink, external

I'm a total noob at this, I'm trying to backup my iPhone on a Windows 10 PC to an external HDD because the SDD internal is too small.

The drive I'm trying to backup to is D Drive.

This following mklink worked in CMD prompt, but have I got it right in order to backup to D drive?

`mklink /J "D:\iTunes Backups" "C:\Users\power\Apple\MobileSync\Backup"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mklink` uses the opposite order of parameters – the *link to be created* needs to be specified first, its target second. So it most likely should have been this:

```
mklink /j "C:\Users\power\Apple\MobileSync\Backup" "D:\iTunes Backups"
```

If you want files to be stored on D:\, then the folder in C:\ should show up as `<JUNCTION>` in cmd's `dir` output or a "link" icon in File Explorer, while the folder in D:\ should not. If you see the junction in D:\ then it goes in the wrong direction.

Comment: That's exactly what happened, the link icon showed in D:\

Comment: That has worked, I thank you for your help, appreciated a lot.